# Automatically populate Django model database tables with unreal data

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I'm working on a template inside one of my apps and I need to have a lot of records in a table to see how it looks like (and several other behaviors) inside the template when queried. I don't want to waste my time inserting over 30 records one by one. I'm trying to do a bulk insert but I have no previously dumped data or such to populate using it.

The correctness of data is not important to me. the quantity is important.

Does that have anything to do with mocking?

I'm not trying to unit test anything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which type of data do you want...??
i mean.. blog posts.. or any other things...try use Faker for django which  provieds fake data.

[Faker - Documentation](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

[Faker - github](https://github.com/joke2k/django-faker)

Comment: instances of my models